# Windows 10 installs on wrong harddrive

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, installation

Yesterday I've bought an expensive MSI notebook and so far I'm very disappointed of its price because there is a lot I have to setup.. So far I did everything with success until I realized everything is installed on the wrong (smaller) drive lol.

I want Windows and all the other programs installed on another drive, on the bigger one.

Here is a picture of how it was installed and the problem is I cannot choose where to install it because Windows will just delete itself and install everything automatically on its own.

Is there a way for me to change that? Please help me, this is very frustrating.

Edit: I have just checked and the bigger drive is even the primary partition. The other, smaller one, is start partition, primary partition. I think here are the problems..?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Will post now. How can I install OS on the small one and all the other programs on the bigger one? :s

Comment: Ok but as example I tried to install Skype. Didn`t ask me where I want install it and it just installed on the smaller too :(
But if you say it's alright then I guess it really is. Because I'm not a pro.

Comment: Skype is relatively small, less than 100 megabytes installed, so I wouldn't worry.  Larger programs and game delivery systems like Steam and Blizzard and most other large programs will ask you where you want to install them and it is those that I would recommend putting on the larger drive, but other than that you are probably fine.  I'm assuming that your system is a 256GB SSD and a 1TB HDD as that is a very common mix and in that case you really do want your OS and most commonly used programs (like Skype which will start at boot) to be on the smaller faster drive.

Comment: Awesome, after your explanation it makes sense now too, thanks a lot and happy new year soon by the way :-)

Comment: You too, I've converted my comments to a full answer and (hopefully) addressed your concerns.  I've also removed my earlier comments to keep it tidy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your screenshot of Disk Manager you have two physical disks, a 1TB disk and a 256GB disk.  It has become quite common for systems these days to have these as a small but fast SSD (the 256GB disk) and a slow but large HDD (1 TB).

You *can* use programs like Macrium Reflect or others to copy your OS to the large drive, but I don't think you really should because the performance and responsiveness of your laptop will suffer.  It can also be a bit of a fiddle to get it to properly boot from the other drive.

On the SSD you would want to install your most commonly used programs and operating system, this means that your system will be fast, responsive and most importantly not waiting for the slow seek times that are the scourge of laptop hard drives.

Addressing your comments regarding programs installing to the smaller drive though, in a lot of cases this is actually preferable.  Many programs will start with Windows and programs like Skype are relatively small, less than 100 megabytes installed. They are low-impact on space, but mean that they are available for use almost immediately on boot, rather than waiting 5 minutes for the slow drive to finish starting before you can phone your parents on Skype.

Larger programs and game delivery systems like Steam, Blizzard and many other programs *should* ask you where you want to install them and it is those that I would recommend putting on the larger drive.  You can also very easily [move your "music", "video" and "photo" libraries](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3025345/windows/move-your-windows-10-libraries-to-a-separate-drive-or-partition.html) to the large drive if you don't want them taking up space on the smaller disk.  This will generally be your preferred option for managing space.

Essentially though you should keep your most often used programs on the SSD as it really will save you time and frustration.  There's nothing more annoying than waiting a minute or more for your slow HDD to open your browser when if you'd put it on the SSD it would have opened in under 5 seconds.

The SSD can really help your productivity because they truly are the key part of a responsive system, while the HDD has the bulk capacity for the big things.